# How do I add a Table Layout to a Java GUI in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, tablelayout

For my employers purposes we are moving from .Net to Java. I have worked with .Net for the better part of the past two years and I have worked with Java for like... two months.
I know very little about it.

A bit of google searching and my employers counsel revealed that NetBeans has a GUI builder, and I've begun working with it and I like what I see. It feels very familiar to me from working with .Net.

However, what my google searches did NOT reveal was the answer to my question that I am asking here, which I suppose is two-fold:

1: What is the Java/Swing/AWT Equivalent to .Nets (C#/VB) TableLayoutPanel component (if one exists)
2: If it does exist, how do I go about adding it to the NetBeans IDE GUI Palette to make use of it? (I'm REALLY hoping it's as easy as drag/drop but I'm not holding my breath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific panel with a table layout, but you can use a regular JPanel and give it a [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html):

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel( );
pane.setLayout( new GridLayout( nrOfRows, nrOfColumns ) );
```

Comment: Ah there it is. Drag/Drop a Swing Containers Panel, right click, set layout. Thank you my good sir.
EDIT: You can also do that for the JFrame (Form?) itself. Now I just need to figure out how to actually do stuff with it...

Comment: The JFrame is indeed close to the Windows Form class, in the sense that it is often used as a top-level window.